# Unable to add Axios Default Headers to VueJS app

Tags: vue.js, axios, http-headers, jwt

So i've tried

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = 'test';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authenticaton'] = 'Bearer slskdf';
```

in both my **main.js** and **index.js** in my router file with beforeEach..... no heaaders show up in the browser at all.

What am I doing wrong to get these headers to appear on EVERY call?

### Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.19 axios no longer uses axios.defaults if you create axios instances to make requests. Set defaults to an instance and use it to make requests.

```
const adapter = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/my-api',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    },
});
adapter.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer test';
adapter.get(...)

See [this issue][1] and [related pull request][1]
```